# Ingress not re-routing angular

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to route an application coexisting with an api with nginx-ingress.
My nginx ingress-controller is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v0.41.2
  Build:         d8a93551e6e5798fc4af3eb910cef62ecddc8938
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.4

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
 kubectl describe service -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.233.38.239
Port:                     http  80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30851/TCP
[... blabla...]
```

I have two deployments (API) with java and (TSP) an angular APP, i reference them in this ingress-resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sit-api
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /tsp/(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
           name: sit-web
           port:
              number: 8080
```

if i describe the ingress ->

```
Rules:
  Host                   Path  Backends
  ----                   ----  --------
  *.example.com
                         /api             sit-api:8080   10.233.90.13:8080,10.233.96.34:8080)
                         /tsp/(/|$)(.*)   sit-web:8080   10.233.92.13:80,10.233.96.36:80)
```

Here it's everything allright, the /api is working as it should. But whenever i try to get anything out of /tsp, i get a 404:

```
 curl -I ctrlnginx.example.com:30851/tsp
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
----
 curl ctrlnginx.example.com:30851/api
{"200":"OK","message":"No message available","path":"/api"}
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the rewrite formula. Could you change the path for `tsp` to: `- path: /tsp(/|$)(.*)` and tell me if that helped? I am going to analyze your issue further in the meantime.

Comment: Hey! sorry, but i found out the solution, i just had to change the angular "--base-href", now it's working fine! Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please post an answer explaining the issue and solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

There was a dumb dumb typo... sorry for late answer.
The line with
 `- path: /tsp/(/|$)(.*)`
had atrailing "/" that had to be removed.
Then FYI: THE INGRESS ANNOTATIONS apply to all the paths within the ingress. So, if you need diferent anotations for each paths, create one ingress for each different path :) thanks all!